# How to execute a jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery code here given by a friend and I'm not sure how to make it work.
I was told that I can save it as html as the code has a reference as external
But when I did it didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>tyu</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css"> 
#tintin
{
    position:relative;
color:white;
font-size:18pt;
font-style:bold;
font-family:Calibri;
width:800px;
height:500px;
}
#text 
{
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
opacity:100;
left:600px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

//var txt=['text 1','text 2', 'text 3', 'text 4', 'text 5', 'text 6', 'text 7', 'text 8', 'text 9', 'text 10'], init=0,i=0,k=0,speed=40,el;
//var loopCount=1000;
//var j=0;
//var padd = 50; //set this to an approriate increment
//function fade(){
//init==0?i++:i--;
//el.filters?el.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+i+')':el.style.opacity=i/100;
//el.firstChild.nodeValue=txt[k];
//if(i==100)init=1;
//if(i==0) {init=0;k++;j++;
//el.style.paddingLeft=50*k;
//} 
//if(k==txt.length)k=0;
//if (j<loopCount) setTimeout('fade()',speed);
//}
//window.onload=function(){
//el=document.getElementById('tintin');
//fade();
    //}
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var txt = ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3', 'text 4', 'text 5', 'text 6', 'text 7', 'text 8', 'text 9', 'text 10'];
        var k = -1;
        fade();
        function fade() {
            k++;
            if (k == 9) {
                k = 0;
            }
            $("#text").text(txt[k]);
            $("#text").css("left", (600 - k * 100) + "px");
            $("#text").fadeTo(1, 100);
            console.log((600 - k * 100) + "px");
            console.log($("#text").css("left"));
            $("#text").css("top", (k * 100) + "px");

            var nl = "-=" + (k*100) + "px";
            console.log(nl);

            var nt = "-=" + (300 - k*100) + "px";
            var op = Math.floor((-($("#text").css("left").replace("px", "") - 600 - k * 100)) / 600) + .3;
            $("#text").animate({
                left: "300px", //
                opacity: op,
                top: "300px"
            }, 1000);

            $("#text").animate({
                left: nl, //
                opacity: 0,
                top: nt
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(fade, 2000);


        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tintin" style="color:#fff !important; background-color:blue;">
<div id="text">

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"I was told that I can save it as html as the code has a reference as external"* That phrase suggests to me you're using some kind of integrated development environment (IDE) and trying to use jQuery with a project in that environment. Which environment are you using? Separately: When you say "a jQuery code", what exactly do you mean? A bunch of lines of code? A file?

Comment: @tintincutes , the above code should work , what error are you getting , use firebug and check error console

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I posted the code. I don't have jQuery IDE. It's my first time. What I got is a suggestion and would like to see it how it works if it's implemented

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In *general*, jQuery code (that is, JavaScript code that uses the jQuery library) runs on the web browser. You run JavaScript code in web browsers using `script` tags, either where the code is actually in the tag:

```
<script>
alert("I'm some JavaScript code");
</script>
```

...or where the code is in a separate file and the tag refers to the file:

```
<script src="myfile.js"></script>
```

(Note that the end tag is required, and you **cannot** write it as a self-closing tag like `<script src="myfile.js"/>`.)

Since you're using jQuery, you must include the jQuery library file *before* any code that uses it:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you're using it from a CDN like Google's:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Code you want to have run when the page is "ready" you can put inside a function that jQuery will call when the page is "ready":

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("<p>This paragraph added via jQuery</p>").appendTo(document.body);
});
</script>
```

Alternately, you can put your `script` tag at the very bottom of your page, just before your closing `</body>` tag; if you do, it's still best to wrap your code in a function so you don't create global symbols unnecessarily:

```
<script>
// This creates a function to contain any symbols that you create, then
// immediately calls it. As written, it assumes it's at the very bottom of
// the page and so things are basically ready.
(function() {
    jQuery("<p>This paragraph added via jQuery</p>").appendTo(document.body);
})();
</script>
```

jQuery's main function, `jQuery`, is available either as `jQuery` or `$`, so the above could be:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("<p>This paragraph added via jQuery</p>").appendTo(document.body);
});
</script>
```

...but as `$` is used by other libraries, there's a way to make jQuery not use the `$` symbol. I mention this so you'll understand why you see `jQuery` in some code, but `$` in other code.

Here's a complete example of using jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test Page</title>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type='button' id='theButton' value='Click Me'>
  <script>
    jQuery(function() {
      // Hook the button click
      jQuery("#theButton").click(function() {
        jQuery("<p>This paragraph was added via jQuery.</p>").appendTo(document.body);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/apona3)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HTML page to test Jquery functionality, if you can provide more examples we can help to resolve them. I found [Cloud 9](http://cloud9ide.com/) to be useful in developing Javascript applications, you can try that out.