# How do I call a JavaScript function that uses jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this function:

```
function squarifyMe(element) {
 squareItUp()
  window.onresize = function(element) {
    squareItUp();
  }
  function squareItUp() {
    $(element).height($(element).width());
  }
}
```

with this call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  squarifyMe('.myElement');
});
```

but don't know how to add it to my webpage...
I've done this a bunch of times but can't get it to work.

Comment: Show your best attempt

Comment: Put it in `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: Looks like jQuery. If so, add the tag to your question.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ ... first code example.

Comment: Where did you find that function in the first place? From the looks of it, without changing the code, it will not work anyway.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5893548/778118).  [Here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is another page you should check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function named *squarifyMe()* uses jQuery.

This means the first thing you have to do is import jQuery.

The easiest way to do that is to use a hosted library.

To use Google's hosted version of jQuery, add this to your html page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you could download jQuery and include it yourself.

.
.
.

Now to explain the second piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    squarifyMe('.myElement');
});
```

The first line basically says "*execute the following code when the page is ready*."

You can **learn more** by reading the documentation for [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

.
.
.

Now to explain the next piece of code:

```
 squarifyMe('.myElement');

 function squareItUp() {
     $(element).height($(element).width());
 }
```

The first line above invokes the function *squarifyMe()* with a string as a parameter when the document is ready.

Inside *squarifyMe()* the function *squareItUp()* is invoked.

It does the following (piece by piece):

```
$('.myElement')
```

This code selects all elements in the document who have the css class *myElement*.

All such elements are returned as a set, which is manipulated by the *chained* jQuery code that follows.

You can **learn more** about *selecting DOM elements by class* [here](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Let's rewrite this line of code for clarity:

```
$(element).height($(element).width());
```

We'll rewrite it like this:

```
var $s = $(element);
$s.height($s.width());
```

Now `$s` equals the set of DOM elements who have the css class `myElement`.

In the second half of the line, we ***GET*** the width of each element in `$s` like this:

```
$s.width()
```

You can **learn more** by reading the documentatino for [`jQuery.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

We then ***SET*** the height of that element to equal its width like this:

```
$s.height($s.width());
```

This will make every element with the class `myElement` a square.

.
.
.

Now to explain the last piece of code:

```
window.onresize = function(element) {
  squareItUp();
}
```

This code registers an event handler for `window.onresize`.

In other words, it causes *squareItUp()* to get invoked whenever the user resizes the browser window.

So... Every time you resize your browser, every DOM element with the class `myElement` will become a square.

You can **learn more** by reading the documentation for [`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the whole code in script tags and import the jquery library.

Make sure that the element you want to "square" has the class "myElement". If it has the id "myElement", you need to change ".myElement" to "#myElement".

Oh, and you need to resize the page to run the function.

Answer (score -3):

Try it.

```
squarifyMe.call('.myElement');
```